# How do I use HTML classes to set Shopify section sizes through CSS?

Tags: css, ruby, shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I'm using Shopify for the first time, which is built on a pretty bewildering combination of different technologies, but I'm fairly certain my actual issue comes down to simple CSS.

In the Shopify theme I'm using, *Motion* by Archetype, the 'fading images' block-type has a minimum height of '250' (actually 250px * 0.65 for some reason). It has a set of hundred-step sizes: 250, 350, 450, etc.

These sizes are, bizarrely, very hardcoded. The controls are defined thus:

```
{
    "type": "range",
    "id": "section_height",
    "label": "Section height",
    "default": 650,
    "min": 250,
    "max": 750,
    "step": 100,
    "unit": "px"
  }
```

and these discrete steps are turned into HTML class names, for some weird reason:

```
<div class="fading-images fading-images--{{ section.id }} fading-images--{{ section.settings.section_height }} fading-images-overlay__overlay loading">
```

Finally, there are a set of static, hardcoded options in the theme's scss:

```
.fading-images--250 {
  height: floor(250px * 0.65);
}

.fading-images--350 {
  height: floor(350px * 0.65);
}

//etc
```

Now, to me this seems restrictive and bizarre. I would like to dynamically set the height to wherever on the slider I damn well please. If I want a div exactly 456px tall, I see no reason why that should be an issue.

To this end, I have added this line to the  section built into the block-type definition, and replaced the size-based classing with a generic one-size-fits-all:

```
<style>
  .fading-images--{{ section.id }} .fading-images__sizer {
    height: {{ section.settings.section_height | times: 0.65 | floor}}px;
  }
  .fading-images--{{ section.id }} .fading-images-overlay__title {
    font-size: {{ section.settings.title_size | times: 0.5 }}px;
  }
  // ...
</style>
```

and

```
<div class="fading-images fading-images--{{ section.id }} fading-images__sizer fading-images-overlay__overlay loading">
```

I am certain the Liquid Ruby bits are working correctly, and that the relevant statement is being resolved properly (eg. "height: 296px;"), but the div isn't actually being sized correctly. Inspecting the div in Chrome's dev tools shows that it has the 'fading-images__sizer' class, but the height attribute just doesn't seem to get changed.

I'm fairly certain this must be some small and stupid problem, but I'm damned if I understand what it is. It's particularly puzzling since very similar statements execute perfectly with the exact same setup - note the font-size statement I included, which works perfectly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you hardcode the element height in the inspector? You do this to verify you're not bumping into a HTML / CSS issue, instead of something Shopify / Liquid specific.

Comment: @Casper Hardcoding the element's height works perfectly. I've tried setting the colour and so on through the style tag, that doesn't seem to work either. I'm pretty sure the CSS is correct, but the selection statement just isn't working.

Comment: You should be able to see your values in the CSS styles of the inspector. Are they there? Note that you can also view the whole CSS file through the inspector. That way you can check if everything you've changed is present as it should be. You just need to narrow it down now. Is it the CSS file, is it the CSS selector, or where is the problem. Maybe a CSS selector is overriding your settings. That should be visible in the inspector also, as it should show which is the overriding CSS statement.

Comment: @Casper Yeah, I checked the inspector. As I said, that statement just doesn't seem to apply any changes at all, suggesting that the selector doesn't work.

I've ended up just using an ugly hack to add in some extra height presets. It's not good, but it works.